# Forwarding a domain to another subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, forwarding, alias, a-record

I have 2 domains jainaditya.in (domain purchased from GoDaddy and currently parked) and techphernalia.com (domain and web hosting from one.com). I created a subdomain ajain.techphernalia.com.

Requirement : When I point to jainaditya.in it should open ajain.techphernalia.com, with addressbar still displaying jainaditya.in.

Working Example : Done similar kind of changes where sms.techphernalia.com is displaying content from some different IP (I do not know from where but lets call this B).

How I did this : Created a CNAME record for sms.techphernalia.com, waited for 2 days, called B and he did some changes on his servers and it reflected.

What is problem : Created CNAME record on jainaditya.in for www.jainaditya.in, request goes out from GoDaddy's servers and reaches one.com servers. But do not know **what changes are required in techphernalia.com DNS records to display content.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In theory** you could do something like this:

1. Create an A record for `jainaditya.in` pointing to the IP address for `ajain.techphernalia.com` (which right now resolves to `46.30.212.96`).  We'd prefer to use a `CNAME` record for this instead of an `A` record, but you can't have a `CNAME` at the apex of a zone.
2. Create another `A` record for `www.jainaditya.in` pointing to the same IP address, assuming you want `www.jainaditya.in` to display the same content.
3. Ask your hosting provider for `ajain.techphernalia.com` (which I guess is one.com) to create two aliases for that domain in their server configuration: `jainaditya.in` and `www.jainaditya.in`.  In Apache this is called a `ServerAlias`, but terminology may vary.

**In reality**, the best way to do what you want is to talk to one.com, tell them what you want to do, and see what they suggest.  I imagine they would want you to move your DNS hosting for `jainaditya.in` over to them so they can manage all the DNS.  That way if they need to change the IP address for `ajain.techphernalia.com` they can update all your DNS records.

Comment: OK, got your point. I thought if only changing DNS settings would work. Since it is creating aliases in Server Configuration so they would not do it on my behalf and I can not do since I can only create one of (Web Alias, Web Forward, A, CNAME). Thanks for all your help @hcsteve

Comment: Used cloud flare and was unable to point @.dom2 -> dom2.dom1 > dom1_ip  CPanel stopped me!!!